# google-dataproc keeps crashing with error 504

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc, http-status-code-504

google-dataproc using pyspark.sql import SparkSession keeps crashing with "504. Thats an error" and none of the notebooks open, is there a solution available?

Comment: Could you please add more information to your question, such as what is the image version, how are you creating the cluster, when are you seeing the error and most importantly, a more detailed stacktrace? Thanks!